# AKS version upgrade error: Operation failed with status: 'Conflict'. Details: Upgrades are disallowed while cluster is in a failed state

Tags: azure, aks

I noticed that one of AKS services is in the failed state. When I went to diagnostics, I found out that current version is not supported anymore. So I tried to follow instructions stated here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/upgrade-cluster

I ran first the command:

```
az aks get-upgrades --resource-group myResourceGroup --name myAKSCluster --output table
```

and then:

```
az aks upgrade --resource-group myResourceGroup --name myAKSCluster --kubernetes-version new_version
```

and that would produce an error:

> Operation failed with status: 'Conflict'. Details: Upgrades are
> disallowed while cluster is in a failed state. For resolution steps
> visit https://aka.ms/aks-cluster-failed to troubleshoot why the
> cluster state may have failed and steps to fix cluster state.

So, state was failed due to old version, and version could not be updated due to failed state...
I checked this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54631309/this-container-service-is-in-a-failed-state but that was not our problem, we had plenty of resources to go around (which we checked with `az aks show --resource-group myResourceGroup  --name myAKSCluster --query agentPoolProfiles`)

Deleting and recreating AKS is not an option.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So after hours of trying different solutions and failing, I found fix for this among the answers here: https://github.com/Azure/AKS/issues/542

In order to fix failed state because of outdated version, I had to simply  do the following:

Upgrade aks to version that is already there. So my version was 1.14.8 and I simply ran:

```
az aks upgrade  --resource-group myResourceGroup  --name myAKSCluster --kubernetes-version 1.14.8
```

which fixed the failed state of the cluster!

After this I just ran upgrade to the correct next version (1.18.19 in my case):

```
az aks upgrade  --resource-group myResourceGroup  --name myAKSCluster --kubernetes-version 1.18.19
```

I hope that this will save someone hours of frustrations :)